# Mongoose wait an operation complete when using helpers functions to call

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, callback

I'm having a problem with mongoose. I just want to verify if an user username already exist in the DB and calling a function to verify this.

The route (/signup), is in the *routes/user.js* file.
The function to verify if the username is already used is in the *lib/mongouser.js* file.

My route handler, in user.js is :

```
// Main routes
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const router = express.Router()
const userLib = require('../lib/mongouser')

/* POST get signup form data */
router.post('/signup', function (req, res, next) {
  let username = req.body.username;

  // Check here if username is already used
  console.log(userLib.checkUsername())
})

module.exports = router
```

And the code in lib/mongouser.js :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

module.exports = {
    checkUsername: function (username) {
        User.count({
            username: username
        }, function (err, count) {
            if (count === 0) {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        })
    }
}
```

('User' schema is right defined)

So the problem is when in router.post, and testing the function with : console.log(userLib.checkUsername()), I'm getting **'undefined'**.

When I copy the content of checkUsername function to the route file, I'm getting the true or false correctly.
I searched about using callback but I cannot find something that I understand correctly, and no examples, explanations seems to be really usable with my methods, or I didn't see them.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User count is asynchronous while you are using it like sync.

in your main route, use like this

```
userLib.checkUsername('your username', function(count) {
 console.log(count);
})
```

and in your lib:

```
checkUsername: function (username, fn) {
    User.count({
        username: username
    }, function (err, count) {
        fn(count);
    })
}
```